# Problem in Topology related to continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

> Let $\mathbb{R-Q}$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. 
>   Is there a function, $f:\mathbb{R-Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R-Q}$ such that f is continuous and $f$ does not have a fixed point?

I get that if we consider the metric of $\mathbb{R}$ every continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ has a fixed point. But we consider $\mathbb{R-Q}$: firstly i cant think of a continuous function from $\mathbb{R-Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R-Q}$ , and given that such a continuous function exits i think it should have a fixed point but im not entirely sure. Can someone give an answer to this problem.?

Comment: "every continuous function from R to R has a fixed point". This is false (see @user60589) for a counter-example).

Comment: What about $x\mapsto x+1$?

Comment: isnt it the case that if f is continuous in a closed interval [a,b] then it has a fixed point?

Comment: Yeah sure but $\Bbb R$ is not a closed interval!!

Comment: Ok thanks i got that.So if we consider the function x-->x+1 for each x in R-Q, it is continuous in R-Q and it has no fixed point in R-Q .(By assuming that it has ,f(c)=c then c+1=c ,which is a contradiction) .. Is it correct? @BrianO

Comment: Right. Clearly it has no fixed point :) The only thing you need to "prove" about it is that it maps irrationals (members of $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$) to irrationals. It's continuous on $\Bbb R$ so it's continuous on the subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Take the addition by a rational

$$ f\colon R\backslash Q \to  R\backslash Q ,  \ x \mapsto x+q$$

for some $q\in Q$.

Comment: If you want this for intervals $l$ without rationals take $f\colon I\backslash Q\to I \backslash Q, \ x \mapsto sx+q$ with $s,q \in Q$ such that this map is a self-map of the interval.